# Change field order in apacite references

Tags: bibliographies, apacite

How can I change the field order in apacite style bibliography. I need the note field to appear as the last one. My references are showing like this:

```
Stacey, K., & MacGregor, M.  (1999).  Learning the algebraic method of solving problems.TheJournal of Mathematical Behavior,18(2), 149 - 167.   [GS Search]   doi: 10.1016/S0732-3123(99)00026-7
```

and I need it like this:

```
    Stacey, K., & MacGregor, M.  (1999).  Learning the algebraic method of solving problems.TheJournal of Mathematical Behavior,18(2), 149 - 167. doi: 10.1016/S0732-3123(99)00026-7 [GS Search]
```

The GS Search is a `\href` link I've put it into a `note` field.

this is the bib

```
@article{stacey1999,
TITLE = "Learning the Algebraic Method of Solving Problems",
JOURNAL = "The Journal of Mathematical Behavior",
VOLUME = "18",
NUMBER = "2",
PAGES = "149 - 167",
YEAR = "1999",
ISSN = "0732-3123",
DOI = "10.1016/S0732-3123(99)00026-7",
AUTHOR = "Kaye Stacey and Mollie MacGregor",
NOTE = "\href{https://scholar.google.com.br/scholar?q='Learning+the+Algebraic+Method+of+Solving+Problems'&btnG=Search}{GS Search}",
}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{apacite} 
\usepackage{hyperref}

\AtBeginDocument{\urlstyle{APACsame}}

\title{Here is the title.}
\author{ John S. Doe }


\begin{document}

\nocite{*}  % to test more entries, not cited in document
\bibliographystyle{apacite} 
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: i've also used these `\RequirePackage{apacite}
 \bibliographystyle{apacite}
 \AtBeginDocument{\urlstyle{APACsame}}`

Comment: I was able to get the .bst from apacite, make a copy and I'm trying to edit to make the changes I need, but with no success sofar. Here's the file: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/PUQyTRkG)

Comment: Can you switch to biblatex/biber with style `apa`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apacite.bst` outputs the `note` field always at the end of a bibliography entry. If you'd use the `url` field to add an URL the `doi` will be printed after the URL:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{stacey1999,
TITLE = "Learning the Algebraic Method of Solving Problems",
JOURNAL = "The Journal of Mathematical Behavior",
VOLUME = "18",
NUMBER = "2",
PAGES = "149 - 167",
YEAR = "1999",
ISSN = "0732-3123",
DOI = "10.1016/S0732-3123(99)00026-7",
AUTHOR = "Kaye Stacey and Mollie MacGregor",
URL = "https://scholar.google.com.br/scholar?q='Learning+the+Algebraic+Method+of+Solving+Problems'&btnG=Search"
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{apacite} 
\usepackage{hyperref}

\AtBeginDocument{\urlstyle{APACsame}}

\title{Here is the title.}
\author{ John S. Doe }


\begin{document}

\nocite{*}  % to test more entries, not cited in document
\bibliographystyle{apacite} 
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: URL before doi]

But in this case you cannot set an URL text different from the URL itself. However at least in printed documents the original URL should be part of the bibliography not only a replacement text. So I think, this would be a good solution.

If you insist on changing the order of `note` and `doi`, you have to

- make a copy of `apacite.bst` into you document directory and rename it, e.g., into `notebeforedoiapacite.bst`,
- goto `FUNCTION {periodical}` (this is lineno 4034–4107),
- move line `format.orig.note` (lineno 4105) before line `url empty$` (lineno  4092),
- save the new file `notebeforedoiapacite.bst`,
- in your document, shown in the question, change `\bibliographystyle{apacite}` into `\bibliography{notebeforedoiapacite.bst}`,
- do one more LaTeX run,
- do one more BibTeX run,
- do one more LaTeX run.

You will get:

[image]

For additional changes like changing the `(…)` around the note into `[…]` see, e.g., `\APACrefnote` in the `apacite` manual.

Please note: Using `biblatex` + `biber` instead of `apacite` + `bibtex` would make it possible to change the output using LaTeX instead of hacking a `bst` file. So I would recommend to switch to `biblatex` + `biber` if possible.

Comment: Thanks man! I had already managed to get there by hacking the bst file. But thanks for the detailed explanation. I will definitely take a look a that and change to a decent implementation.